# Querying Redshift Permissions via Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Question:
"For each user, show me the groups they belong (1) to and the tables they can query as a result of being part of that group (2)."

Details: This is on redshift.

I'm curious if anyone has done anything like this.

The first part isn't hard, I did that with this:

```
SELECT usename, groname
FROM pg_user,
pg_group
WHERE pg_user.usesysid = ANY (pg_group.grolist)
AND pg_group.groname in (SELECT DISTINCT pg_group.groname from pg_group)
```

The second part is much harder I think. Showing table permissions isn't, but that's not really what's being asked. That can be accomplished with this:

```
SELECT has_table_privilege(user, table, 'select'::text) as select...
```

But that does not show which group gives the user that permission.

Any advice is great!

Comment: Looks as if you would need to query the system views such as SVV_RELATION_PRIVILEGES (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_RELATION_PRIVILEGES.html)

Comment: Yuppp I think that's it.

Comment: If you want to add an answer, I'll give it to you. The query I ended up creating was this:
```SELECT usename, namespace_name, relation_name, privilege_type, identity_name
FROM pg_user,
  pg_group
      JOIN (SELECT namespace_name, relation_name, privilege_type, identity_name
            FROM svv_relation_privileges
            ) t ON t.identity_name = pg_group.groname
WHERE pg_user.usesysid = ANY (pg_group.grolist)
AND pg_group.groname in (SELECT DISTINCT pg_group.groname from pg_group)```

Comment: Please go ahead and answer your question. Glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of MP24 the answer I came to was this:

```
SELECT usename, namespace_name, relation_name, privilege_type, identity_name 
FROM pg_user,   pg_group       
JOIN (
SELECT namespace_name, relation_name, privilege_type, identity_name             
FROM svv_relation_privileges             
) t ON t.identity_name = pg_group.groname 
WHERE pg_user.usesysid = ANY (pg_group.grolist) 
AND pg_group.groname in (SELECT DISTINCT pg_group.groname from pg_group)
```